# sqlite INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS and get the id?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, insert, system.data.sqlite

is it possible to get the id even if I use  INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS?
how to modify it so it will bring me the id of the inserted record or the id of the already existed record? if possible at all!

```
INSERT INTO Timeline (name, ts)
SELECT @name, @ts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Timeline WHERE name=@name AND ts = @ts);
```

i have a column called "**id**" with auto increment integer
how I can get the value of the ID?

cheers

Comment: With that statement, it will insert the new record if it doesn't already exists on your table. Its a perfectly valid statement

Comment: I know, my question on how to make it bring me the id or the value of the id column?

Comment: You want to know if a row was inserted or if a row was already present?  Won't rowcount tell you?

Answer (score 1):

You are guaranteeing that `(name,ts)` is unique, so this should do the trick.

```
INSERT INTO Timeline (name, ts)
SELECT @name, @ts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Timeline WHERE name=@name AND ts = @ts);

SELECT id, name, ts from TimeLine
WHERE name=@name AND ts = @ts
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the output clause:

```
insert into Timeline output inserted.name 
SELECT @name, @ts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Timeline WHERE name=@name AND ts = @ts);
```

you can do it on the update too

```
update Timeline 
set name = @name
output deleted.name as OLD_NAME, inserted.name as NEW_NAME
```

EDITED:

run this and you will understand:

```
create table Timeline(
id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
name varchar(50),
ts varchar(50))

insert into timeline output inserted.ID
values ('first record', 'ts') 
--it will show 1


insert into Timeline output inserted.ID 
SELECT 'first record', 'ts'
union select 'new record', 'ts'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Timeline WHERE name='first record' AND ts = 'ts')
--ir will show 2 because the 1 already exits
```

Comment: can you explain the "output inserted.name " part! note sure if I understand it

Comment: it seems i was not clearer in explaining the issue, sorry for that, now I edited the question, hope it is clear now!

Comment: it will work the same way, I used name as an example. Try changing it to ID and you will see the new Ids inserted

Comment: sorry I don't know. I did not realize the sqlite tag. Was testing on sql server 2005.  I apologize