# SQlite: select with insert if not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, insert

Let's suppose we have a table defined with:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signals(sigid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)

This table initially is  empty.
I would like to get the **sigid** for a given **name** with a select and in case **name** does not exist, add it and get the new autoincremented id.

I would like to use this query in order to autogenerate ,when needed, a new id that is used as foreign key in another table. I must put attention to the performances so I cannot proceed as :

1. check if name is present and return id witha a **SELECT**
2. if returned id is null create a new entry with an **INSERT**
3. get the new id again with a new **SELECT**

Is it possible do it with a single **SELECT**-like query ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think with an single select no.
Let's say i want to insert id_build = 3, hashed_value = 1 into the big table 'crash'.

The code in example makes first select to check if the value was already in the table, if yes skips the insert with `where .. is null` then retrive the id from already saved into temporary table.
 example :

```
create temporary table if not exists Variablez(Name TEXT primary key on conflict replace, Value TEXT);            --storing vars
insert into Variablez(Name, Value) values ('tmp_id', (select id_crash from crash where hashed_value = "1" ));     --put id if was existing
insert into crash(id_build, hashed_value) select 3, 1 where (select Value from Variablez where Name = 'tmp_id' ) is null; -- insert if not exists

select 
     case
        when (select Value from Variablez where name = 'tmp_id' ) is null then 
            '0'
        else
            '1'
    end 
as existing,
    case
        when (select Value from Variablez where name = 'tmp_id' ) is null then 
            (select id_crash from crash where hashed_value = "1")
        else
            (select Value from Variablez where name = 'tmp_id')
    end 
as id_returned;
```

Answer (score -2):

if the table is empty and you are the one filling it in just one shot (and you don't need to do it again later on when there is data in the table), AND you don't have too many rows, then you could just cache the names you have already inserted and look them up in memory.

It's more of a comment, I guess.

there is also this for getting the last inserted id:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

But if the above applies, you are even faster by assigning the ids yourself, and not define it as AUTOINCREMENT. Then you don't need to get the last inserted id, you just keep a counter and all the names inserted and increment for each new name you find.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signals(sigid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT)`

```
 List<String> insertedNames = new List<String>();
 int count = 0;
 while(input.hasNext())
 {
    String name = input.next();
    if( !insertedNames.contains(name) )
    {
       var sql = "insert into table (sigid,name) VALUES (" + count + ", " + name + ")";
       executeSql(sql);
       insertedNames.add(name);
       count++;
    }
 }
```

answering your comment

```
public int getId( string name )
{
   String sql = "select id from table where name='" + name + "'";
   int theIdForTheName = executeAndGetFirstColumnAsInt(sql);
   return theIdForTheName;
}
```

i don't know what else to tell you...

Comment: I've already found this option but it is not what I'm looking for. When I ask for the id of an already existing name it could return me the wrong id. For Example lets suppose to add in order "CAT"->id=1 "DOG"->id=2 "FISH"->id=3. When I send a query for "CAT" it will return me id=3 (the last inserted id) , that is the wrong id.

Comment: to answer your comment, i need to see your code, here is what i would do: `select id from table where name='CAT'`

Comment: let's incapsulate this query in a function getid(name). calling in order getid("DOG"),getid("CAT"),getid("DOG"),getid("FISH"),getid("CAT"),getid("BUNNY") should return in order 1,2,1,3,2,4 the last_inserted_id is not always what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't have other code except the one i posted to create the table. If i call select id from table where name='CAT' it will return an empty result and it wont add the record "CAT" in the table. I need a query that always return a valid ID, eventually obtained after an insert

Comment: Basically, i need an SQL line that acts like: if name exists in signals return id of name else insert (null,name) in signals and return id of name. I need that works in different executions so I cannot cache the added id. I would prefer to do it in a single SQL query.

Comment: do it with a stored procedure (does sqlite support those?) and then you can do it in one line... where are the sql wizards?

Comment: SQLite does not support the stored procedures. However I've found a question that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212782/sqlite-insert-into-where-not-exists-and-get-the-id